# my dropdown menu menu will not go in front of the other elements

Tags: html, css

Inside the grid there is a drop down button but the dropdown content goes behind the content in the next column under how do I fix this as each column needs to have the same dropdown button so the dropdown content needs to be in front of everything else I tried giving it the highest z-index but this hasn't worked. my code is below

```css
.grid-item {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid orangered;
  text-align: center;
  height: 210px;
  top: 40px;
  }


.purchases-options-sort-dropbtn {
  background-color: #fd886b;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  right: 60px;
  border: 1px solid orangered;
  top: 80px;
}

.purchases-options-sort-dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #f76f4d;
}

.purchases-options-sort-dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  width: 250px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: center;
  top: 131px;
  left: 63px;
}

.purchases-options-sort-dropdown-content a {
  color: #818181;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
}

.purchases-options-sort-dropdown-content a:hover {
  color: white;
  transition: 0.5s;
  
}

.purchases-options-sort-select a:hover {background-color: orangered;}

.show {display: block;}
/*end of sort dropdown menu */
```

```html
<div class="grid-item">
  <a  href="#" role="button" alt="Leave Feedback" type="button" class="leave-feedback-btn">
    <span>Leave feedback</span>
  </a>
  <div class="purchases-options-sort-select">
    <button onclick="myitemssort()" class="purchases-options-sort-dropbtn">Options &#9660;</button>
    <div id="sortDropdown" class="purchases-options-sort-dropdown-content">
      <a href="#home">Details </a>
      <a href="#home">Contact user </a>
      <a href="#about">Cancel order</a>
      <a href="#about">Request a refund/item</a>
      <a href="#about">Return this item</a>
      <a href="#about">View sellers other items</a>
      <a href="#about">View similar items</a>
      <a href="#about">Sell one similar</a>
      <a href="#about">Save seller</a>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="my-items">
```

Comment: can you include your JS?

Comment: your provided code, missing to much to reproduce this error. Please provide all your necessary code not just a small part of it.

Comment: Check z-index of ``.purchases-options-sort-dropdown-content {...}`` - looks like no z-index applied which might explain why it appears behind objects. The higher the value determines whether it appears in front of other objects or not.